# how to write this VBA program without recursion

Tags: vba

Below is an example code. It traverse all sub-directory of given directory and prints the directory and file names in immediate window.Question is how program is calling the "TraversePath" within itself in this line " TraversePath path & directory & "\" " ? . It is recursion..then is there any better way to code this ? because unless we use recursion in a correct context there is always a chance of overflow.

```
Sub TraversePath(path As String)
    Dim currentPath As String, directory As Variant
    Dim dirCollection As Collection
    Set dirCollection = New Collection

    currentPath = Dir(path, vbDirectory)

    'Explore current directory
    Do Until currentPath = vbNullString
        Debug.Print currentPath
        If Left(currentPath, 1) <> "." And _
            (GetAttr(path & currentPath) And vbDirectory) = vbDirectory Then
            dirCollection.Add currentPath
        End If
        currentPath = Dir()
    Loop

    'Explore subsequent directories
    For Each directory In dirCollection
        Debug.Print "---SubDirectory: " & directory & "---"
    'How program is calling/executing below line of code
        TraversePath path & directory & "\"
    Next directory

End Sub

Sub Testprogram()

    TraversePath "D:\VBA\"

End Sub
```

Comment: This is recursion. It is a standard tool in computer science. Traversing trees is a common use-case for it. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your worries about stack overflow are misplaced in this use of recursion. For example,

```
Sub PlumbDepth(ByVal n As Long)
    Debug.Print n
    n = n + 1
    PlumbDepth n
End Sub
```

When I enter

```
PlumbDepth 1
```

In the Immediate Window, I don't get an out of stack space error until I have done over 6000 recursive calls. For walking a file system, unless you have things like

```
C:\MyDocuments\MySecretDocuments\MySecretSecretDocuments\...\MySecretSecretSecretSecret....(5000 secrets later)Documents
```

you are not going to blow the stack. I suspect that the OS would object long before it becomes an issue. The only valid reason to use a non-recursive algorithm in this context is if the recursive one takes too long due to function-call overhead.

Answer (score 1):

A better way could be this:

```
Public Sub NonRecursiveMethod()
    Dim fso, oFolder, oSubfolder, oFile as variant 
    Dim queue As Collection

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set queue = New Collection
    queue.Add fso.GetFolder("D:\VBA") 'obviously replace

    Do While queue.Count > 0
        Set oFolder = queue(1)
        queue.Remove 1 'dequeue
        '...insert any folder processing code here...
        For Each oSubfolder In oFolder.SubFolders
            queue.Add oSubfolder 'enqueue
            Debug.Print oSubfolder
        Next oSubfolder
        For Each oFile In oFolder.Files
            '...insert any file processing code here...
            Debug.Print oFile
        Next oFile
    Loop

End Sub
```